# Importing Project file to SharePoint task list without MS Project

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, task-list, ms-project

I have an MPP file which I wish to display on a SharePoint task list.

Is it possible to do this without opening the document up in MS Project first and syncing it there.

Everything I have found points me to opening it in MS Project.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to importing MPP file directly into SharePoint 2010.